Internal speaker Not Working on Ubuntu 24.10 (Samsung Galaxy Book 4 Pro)
I installed Ubuntu 24.10 (The latest version of the Ubuntu operating system for desktop PCs and laptops)on my Samsung Galaxy Book 4 Pro with the following specifications:
Processor: Intel Core i7-155H (Meteor Lake-P)
Audio Controller: Meteor Lake-P HD Audio Controller
While sound output works through wired headphones and HDMI, the internal speaker does not work.
Here’s what I’ve tried:
Updated and upgraded the system via terminal.
Verified the speaker is not muted using ALSA Mixer.
Checked system details:
aplay -l shows sof-hda-dsp devices, including HDA Analog and HDMI outputs.
cat /proc/asound/cards identifies the card as sof-hda-dsp.
lspci -v | grep -i "audio" confirms the audio controller is using the sof-audio-pci-intel-mtl kernel driver.
Loaded kernel modules include snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_mtl, and others related to sof-hda-dsp.
Despite these checks, the internal speaker is not producing any sound. External devices, such as wired headphones and HDMI-connected speakers, work without issues.
I tried to install Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS for desktop also, however, I encounter same problem.
How can I troubleshoot and resolve this problem? Any suggestions would be appreciated!
